# Why is the JQuery status callback parameter a string rather than a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any reason why the status callback parameter called `textStatus` of the `complete` and `error` functions, which themselve are defined on the `jqXHR` object, is a string? I would expect the status to be a number (besides the name, which already suggests the parameter to be a string).

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ :  *string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "nocontent", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").*  most likely called "*text*Status" to make it completely clear that it is **not** a number.

Comment: You can already get the status *number* from the jqXHR:  `XMLHttpRequest.status`

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would it be a number?

jQuery returns the following values in the `textStatus` argument

- success
- notmodified
- nocontent
- error
- timeout
- abort
- parsererror

These are all custom messages in jQuery to tell what you wen't wrong, or if the request succeeded.

Any errors the server sends, such as a `404 Not Found` or `403 Forbidden` are generally considered successful requests by jQuery.

The custom error codes above are thrown by jQuery when for instance a request times out after a specific time has been reached, or if the content couldn't be parsed by jQuery etc.
These strings aren't part of the original `XMLHttpRequest`, but are added by jQuery as a convenience.

Comment: Okay that explains a lot. Thank you. It was somewhat not clear at the first time i looked at it. I thought they refer to the actual request status.